# Convert data table to json

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a data table in c# having content like :

```
firstName lastName email                   password
Alpha     Tango    AlphaTango@domain.com   123
Charle    Tango    CharlieTango@domain.com 456
```

I need to convert this datatable into json with below format.

```
{
    "columns": [ 
      "firstName", 
      "lastName", 
      "email", 
      "password",
    ],
    "rows": [
      [
        "Alpha",
        "Tango",
        "AlphaTango@domain.com",
        "123"
      ],
      [
        "Charle",
        "Tango",
        "CharlieTango@domain.com",
        "456"
      ]
    ]
}
```

I could get the rows converted into json array of arrays via `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.ItemArray))`
but I am unable to get the entire json(having rows and columns). Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Customize json string, i think you have to make it manually at your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
   columns = dt1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName),
   rows = dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.ItemArray),
});
```

I've made a simple fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/T5Gs8l

The result seems to be exactly what you are expecting:

```
{
  "columns": [
    "firstName",
    "lastName",
    "email",
    "password"
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "Alpha",
      "Tango",
      "AlphaTango@domain.com",
      "123"
    ],
    [
      "Charlie",
      "Tango",
      "CharlieTango@domain.com",
      "456"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Note that you lose the type information, so if your columns might be of varied datatypes, deserializing the object back to the same datatable might be tricky (you may need to infer the column types from the values).

I'd probably store more information on the columns if I was to deserialize it.